# Error 803 on previously working query - " Some of the aliases you requested do not exist"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I used to call this function to get facebook friends ...

`FB.api('/fql&q=SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 0', function(response) {`

but suddenly , this morning.. it doesn't work anymore, and i got this error msg....

```
FB.ApiServer._callbacks.f507d012c({"error":{"message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: fql&q=SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1","type":"OAuthException","code":803}});
```

what happened? Did facebook just remove this function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct usage of the SDK is:

```
FB.api('fql', { q: 'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 0' }, function(response) { /* ... */ });
```

In general, the path that you have specified is not valid in its current state. Characters like space and () are not allowed. URL query strings must be properly encoded. You might be fortunate and your FQL will be properly URL-encoded, but you shouldn't chance it. Use the SDK's proper inferface as I have done above.

Answer (score 2):

You've got an error in your code.

Your API call starts with `/fql&q=QUERY`, it should be `/fql?q=QUERY`

Comment: i changed to /fql?q=QUERY ...and got this error 'FB.ApiServer._callbacks.f36394fce8({"error":{"message":"(#601) Parser error: unexpected end of query.","type":"OAuthException","code":601}});'

Comment: Actually this code works before, just this morning, it suddenly broke

Comment: From facebook Doc... It  is FB.api('/fql&q=SELECT .......https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/

Comment: That part of the Facebook doc was poorly written and clearly never reviewed or tested. I reported it as being wrong and they improved it without actually making it right.

Answer (score -2):

I checked the doc form facebook official website.. it has exactly same api call as i do..
Still don't know why this error is happening

```
 FB.api('/fql&q=SELECT uid, name, is_app_user, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1',
```

function(response) { ...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/

Comment: Report a documentation bug, that's not how you form the query.